# Replacing Interlocking Ceiling Tiles From The "Wrong" Direction

Tags: ceiling, adhesive

A section of ceiling above my front door has been damaged due to a leaky roof, so I need to replace around half of the 7' x 9'-ish entry area. The existing tiles are stapled to furring. However, based on the way the tiles intersect with each other, I can tell they were installed starting at the front door, and then inward into the house. I can't staple new tiles in because the lip where the staple would go needs to be inserted into the existing tile. The tiles in question are [Armstrong 12" x 12" ceiling tiles](https://www.armstrongceilings.com/residential/en-us/suspended-ceiling-systems/12-x-12-ceiling-tiles/item/231.html#redirect_term=231):

My first thought was to install the new tiles the "wrong" way, and use adhesive instead of staples. However, the adhesive I bought (Henry 237 AcoustiGum) specifically says not to use on wood surfaces. After googling a bit, I can't find any mention of someone using adhesive on wood furring. Note that I haven't opened the AcoustiGum, so if another adhesive is required, I'm fine with returning it for something else.

Is there a way for me to avoid replacing the entire room? (*One the one hand, I'd like to save myself unnecessary effort, as well as avoid replacing perfectly good tiles. However, I also don't want to do a shoddy job*.)

I'm not particularly knowledgeable about home repair, so any input would be appreciated. If I haven't adequately described the problem, please let me know, and I'll try to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the Armstrong web site from the link you left they state that these particular tiles should NOT be stapled (for whatever reasons) and the warranty will be voided if done so.

There is also a question asked in their FAQ's asking this same problem :"can tiles be stapled?"  The rep answers with a curt yes and continues to reiterate the warranty void issue. That's all that's said.

I would try to remove the staples from the tiles that border the damaged area. Since that's what is preventing the new ones from being installed. Once the first new tiles are installed the remaining new ones will go in as per manufacturer's instruction.

As for method of securing them; the company states glue (like the Henry's you purchased) or their "ceiling track" (which doesn't work with your existing tiles). The "Accusto-Gum" adhesive is recommended for plaster and drywall surfaces. You may want to consider using an adhesive with more holding power. Any construction adhesive should hold. Staples or Henry's adhesive both are not advised for your repair. The staples have held for how long? Use both for increased holding power.

Comment: I should probably add that the area that needs to be replaced is basically the front half of the ceiling (the half closest to the outer wall). So it's not a hole, it's three walls and a row of good tiles.

Comment: The tiles have been there at least since I bought the house 14 years ago. I have no idea how long they were there before that.

Comment: I understood the tile layout SloppyNick. What I;m saying is since the company is sending contradictory answers I believe you will have to go by instinct. Do you feel confident with my suggestion to use construction adhesive and staples? This is basically the last resort for keeping tile in place securely. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, I feel confident enough to go with the construction adhesive and staples. Thanks for your help.